# Can you find a counter-example for this proposed Graph Isomorphism algorithm?

Tags: graph-isomorphism, puzzles

As D. Eppstein pointed out [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/1065/8237) regarding proposed poly-time algorithms for Graph Isomorphism:

> ... it is easy to define algorithms for graph isomorphism
> that attempt to amplify some sort of subtle asymmetry in the graph to
> the point where it is obvious how to match the vertices to each other,
> and it is hard to find counterexamples for these algorithms, but that
> is very different from having a clear proof of correctness that works
> for all graphs.

As a (hopefully fun) exercise, here is such an algorithm.  Can you find a counterexample?

**input:** two *connected* undirected graphs $G_1=(V_1, E_1)$, $G_2=(V_2, E_2)$
**output:** 'yes' if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic, 'no' otherwise (with high probability)

1. let $U=\{0,1,\ldots, 2^n-1\}$; let $h: U\times U \rightarrow U$ be a universal hash function
2. for every pair of vertices $v_1\in V_1$ and $v_2\in V_2$:
3. $~~~$ let $\ell_0(v_1) = \ell_0(v_2) = 1$ and $\ell_0(v) = 0$ for $v\in V_1\cup V_2\setminus\{v_1, v_2\}$
4. $~~~$ for $t \gets 1, 2, \ldots, T$, where $T=n^2$:
5. $~~~~~~$ for each vertex $v\in V_1 \cup V_2$:
6. $~~~~~~~~~$ let $u_1, \ldots, u_d$ be $v$'s neighbors, ordered so $\ell_{t-1}(u_1) \le \ell_{t-1}(u_2) \le \cdots \le \ell_{t-1}(u_d)$
7. $~~~~~~~~~$ let $\ell_t(v) = h(\ell_{t-1}(u_d), h(\ell_{t-1}(u_{d-1}), h(\ldots, h(\ell_{t-1}(u_{2}), h(\ell_{t-1}(u_1), \ell_{t-1}(v))\ldots)))$
8. $~~~$ let $u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n$ be the vertices in $V_1$, ordered so $\ell_T(u_1) \le \ell_T(u_2) \le \cdots \le \ell_T(u_n)$
9. $~~~$ let $w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_n$ be the vertices in $V_2$, ordered so $\ell_T(w_1) \le \cdots \le \ell_T(w_n)$
10. $~~~$ if the bijection given by $u_i \leftrightarrow w_i$ is an isomorphism, return 'yes'
11. return 'no'

Note that we are only considering isomorphism of *connected* graphs.  Line 2 "guesses" that there is an isomorphism that maps $v_1$ to $v_2$; the body of the loop looks for such an isomorphism.  Line 7 defines $\ell_t(v)$ to be a hash of $\ell_{t-1}(v)$ and the multiset of $\ell_{t-1}(w)$'s for the neighbors $w$ of $v$.

The algorithm hashes polynomially many values into an exponentially large universe $U$, so the probability of a collision is exponentially small. (By a "collision", we mean that, among the hashes $h(x_i, y_i)$ that the algorithm computes, there are $h(x_i, y_i)$ and $h(x_j, y_j)$ such that $(x_i, y_i) \ne (x_j, y_j)$ but $h(x_i, y_i) = h(x_j, y_j)$.)

Assuming there are no such collisions, $\ell_T(v)$ uniquely identifies the *$T$-neighborhood* of $v$, where the $t$-neighborhood of $v$ consists of the pair formed by the $(t-1)$-neighborhood of $v$ and the multiset of $(t-1)$-neighborhoods of $v$'s neighbors. As a base case, the $0$-neighborhoods of $v_1$ and $v_2$ are each $1$, while the $0$-neighborhood of each $v\not\in\{v_1,v_2\}$ is 0.  If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic by an isomorphism $f$ such that $f(v_1)=v_2$, then the $t$-neighborhoods of vertices $u\in V_1$ and $w\in V_2$ such that $f(u) = w$ will be the same for all $t$.  The underlying question is to what extent the converse holds.

By inspection the algorithm returns 'yes' only if $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic.  To make it  fail, one approach is to find a connected graph $G$ such that for every pair of vertices $v_1$ and $v_2$ (as chosen in Line 2) such that $G$ has an automorphism that maps $v_1$ to $v_2$, there are two vertices $u$ and $w$ with the same $T$-neighborhoods but where no such automorphism maps $u$ to $w$.  (Then, given two copies of $G$, the algorithm could incorrectly return 'no', because $u$ and $w$ can be ordered one way in Line 8 and the other way in Line 9.)  I would consider such a graph $G$ as an acceptable answer to the question.

It seems that such a graph $G$ should exist, for otherwise the (hashed) $T$-neighborhoods could give a poly-sized (albeit randomized) witness certifying that $G$ has no non-trivial automorphism.  It [seems unlikely](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3064/conp-certificate-for-graph-isomorphism) that this is possible.

*p.s.* It seems likely that this or a similar algorithm has already been studied. (E.g., it would be natural to replace the use of a hash to encode the $t$-neighborhood of $v$ by a signature that encodes the set of vertices $w$ that have different $t$-neighborhoods...)  If so, please leave a comment to let me know, thanks.

Comment: Even without the hash function, this is basically just 1-d Weisfeiler-Leman with individualization of a single vertex. The Cai-Furer-Immerman graphs should give a pretty strong counterexample

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow: Perfect, thanks.  If you want to post that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Well, I have to think for a few minutes about the individualization part, but won't be able to get to that for a bit.

Comment: Here's a link to (a translation of) the Weisfeller-Leman paper: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=1%2C22&q=THE+REDUCTION+OF+A+GRAPH+TO+CANONICAL+FORM+AND+THE+ALGEBRA+WHICH+APPEARS+THEREIN

Comment: Indeed, I'm still not sure if the CFI graphs alone would be a counterexample to your approach bc of the individualization part. But the Neuen-Schweitzer paper in my answer shows how to build even stronger counterexamples using CFI as (roughly) a starting point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even without the hash function, this is basically just 1-dimensional Weisfeiler-Leman with individualization of a single vertex. Neuen & Schweitzer ([STOC '18](https://doi.org/10.1145/3188745.3188900), [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.03283)) gave examples with an exponential $2^{\Omega(n)}$ lower bound for a much stronger family of algorithms, namely those for which one can iteratively individualize & refine, and even use $k$-dimensional WL for the refinement.