# "Refined" list of open problems in TCS

Tags: reference-request, big-list, open-problem

In the conference on learning theory (COLT), a list of open problems is published every year, [for example, the list of 2019](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v99/#open).

The open problems are being submitted and peer reviewed, which makes this list reliable (in the sense that the problems are well-defined, motivated and "accessible").

In the area of sublinear algorithms and property testing, [there is this wiki page](https://sublinear.info/index.php?title=Main_Page), which similarity includes a list of open problems.

My question is: are there similar lists for other areas in TCS (e.g. complexity, cryptography etc.)? I didn't find such a list in common conferences, and I wonder if there are blogs/websites with a list of known open problems (which are accessible in some sense, i.e. not just "p,np" and problems at that level)

Comment: Like this? https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1015/129

Comment: Also: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/38560/sources-of-open-problems.

Comment: thanks! I am aware of those lists. My question is about either maintained projects (such that the sublinear algorithms project), or about peer reviewed sources (such as the COLT one). A blog of a known researcher for example, or a project maintained by a community of reputable authors

Answer (score 4):

There is a list of [open problems in computational geometry](http://cs.smith.edu/%7Ejorourke/TOPP/). It is edited and maintained by Demaine, Mitchell, and O'Rourke.

Comment: Thanks, I will add this source to the question

Comment: This was one of the resources I linked to in the list above.

Answer (score 3):

There is a list of [open problems in graph theory and combinatorics](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ewest/openp/) collected and maintained by Douglas B. West.

[This page](http://fpt.wikidot.com/open-problems) maintains a list of lists of open problems in parameterized complexity.

Comment: The parameterized complexity page also appears in the list I linked to above.

Answer (score 2):

There's the [TLCA List of Open Problems](http://tlca.di.unito.it/opltlca/), collecting unsolved problems in $\lambda$-calculi and related areas, such as proof theory, semantics and theory of programming languages.  It is maintained by Ryu Hasegawa, Luca Paolini and Paweł Urzyczyn.

There's also a related list, the [RTA list of open problems](https://www.win.tue.nl/rtaloop/), concerning rewriting theory.  At some point it was maintained by Nachum Dershowitz and Ralf Treinen, but it seems to have not been updated in a while.

Comment: Both lists don't seems to be under active and recent curation. That's a shame, since so many new and interesting new open problems have shown up in the last decade.