# Evidence for $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{PP}$ if the polynomial hierarchy collapses?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, sat, big-picture, polynomial-hierarchy, pspace

We think that $\mathsf{PH}$ does not collapse, and that $\mathsf{PP}$ is not in $\mathsf{P}$.

Suppose on the contrary that $\mathsf{PH}$ does collapse, say even $\mathsf{P}= \mathsf{NP}$.

$\mathsf{PP}$ still seems like it would be of reach.

What evidence do we have that $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{PP}$, under that assumption, i.e., evidence that does not apply to $\mathsf{P}$ vs. $\mathsf{NP}$?

$\underline{\mbox{Assumption}}$: Note if $\mathsf{SAT}$ is in linear time then perhaps $\mathsf{P=PSPACE}$ might follow as composition of linear time is linear time?

$\underline{\mbox{Following is only based on if above assumption follows}}$:

1. Perhaps the problem would be

   1a. why believe $\mathsf{SAT}$ is in superlinear time

   1b. and if there is reason to believe $\mathsf{SAT}$ is in superlinear time then why believe $\mathsf{PP}$ requires $\Omega(\log\log n)$ quantifications?
2. Do evidences provided by https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2018/107/ and http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.03398 still hold up in face of $\mathsf{P=NP}$ and $\mathsf{SAT}$ in linear time ($\mathsf{P=NP}$ seems to invalidate second)?

Comment: Why the downvotes? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is it plausible that $\mathsf{PH}$ collapses but that $\mathsf{P}\neq \mathsf{\# P}$? That sounds more tractable and an affirmative answer would be an affirmative answer to this question.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow Would your comment in https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/198 and relations among $P$, $NP$, $NL$, $GapL$ and $GapP$ address $P=NP\neq PP$?

Answer (score 2):

The scaled down version of $\mathsf{PH}$ versus $\mathsf{PP}$ is $\mathsf{AC}^0$ versus $MAJ \circ \mathsf{AC}^0$, and we know that for the latter there is an exponential separation. Of course, this separation doesn't propagate exponentially up, but you could take this as philosophical evidence that $\mathsf{PH}$ is different enough from $\mathsf{PP}$ that perhaps that remains true even if $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NP} = \mathsf{PH}$. (In fact, following this line of reasoning, I'd guess you can build an oracle relative to which $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{NP} \neq \mathsf{PP}$.)

Comment: I think $\mathsf{PP}$ corresponds to $MAJ \circ polylog$ where $polylog$ is _any_ gate with polylogarithmic fan-in. And we know that $MAJ$ itself is already not in $\mathsf{AC}^0$. Therefore scaling up we get $\mathsf{PP} \not \subseteq \mathsf{PH}$ in some relativized world.