# Is there an oracle that separates $PH$ from counting classes?

Tags: counting-complexity, oracles

Is there an oracle $A$ for which $P^A =PH^A \neq CH^A = NEXP^A$ holds?

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure why there are down votes and close votes... what's wrong with this question? Too short, not well-researched?

Comment: We have $P^A=PH^A\neq CH^A$ from https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/44503/evidence-for-mathsfp-neq-mathsfpp-if-the-polynomial-hierarchy-collapses. However it does not give $CH^A=NEXP^A$.