# Evidence integer multiplication is in linear time?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, time-complexity, turing-machines, complexity

After millenia of quest we have identified two $n$ bit integers can be multiplied in $O(n\log n)$ time. Please refer details in https://www.quantamagazine.org/mathematicians-discover-the-perfect-way-to-multiply-20190411/. The problem of placing multiplication in $O(n)$ time is [still unsolved](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/21335).

1. What evidence do we have that this can/cannot be brought to $O(n)$ time on uniform Turning model?
2. What evidence do we have that this can/cannot be brought to $O(n)$ complexity in a reasonable non-uniform model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to (2), conditional super-linear lower bounds are known. A recent preprint by [Afshani, Freksen, Kamma, and Larsen](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.10935) proves an $\Omega(n \log n)$ lower bound for the size of Boolean circuits computing integer multiplication, assuming a certain conjecture on network coding in undirected graphs. (See also [this blog post](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2019/04/30/network-coding-yields-lower-bounds/) and [a follow-up post](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2019/05/06/the-network-coding-conjecture-is-powerful/).)

From the [linked post on major unsolved problems](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/174/major-unsolved-problems-in-theoretical-computer-science/21335#21335), a super-linear lower bound [follows from the Heartmanis-Stearns conjecture](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/why-the-hartmanis-stearns-conjecture-is-still-open/).